# virtual box connecting to different network on host and guest

Tags: networking, virtualbox

On my mac, I'm running virtual box with a linux guest OS. My mac is connected to a network using the wifi card. Is it possible for the guest to also use that wifi card but to connect to a different wireless network?

Comment: There is a way! check out the below forum https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=26650

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible for two reasons:

1) The guest OS does not have access to the wireless hardware itself. Only the host OS does. VirtualBox can only bridge to an existing network connection via a virtual network adapter.  Basically, your Mac's wireless card is treated as a virtual Ethernet switch by VirtualBox.  Each VM gets plugged into a port on that switch.  The VMs don't know they're on a wireless network at all.

2) The 802.11x specs define two types of wireless devices: an end point and an access point.  A wireless device can be one or the other, but not both.  An access point has multiple radios and additional hardware for controlling the management band and time division of the radio signal.  The wireless card in your Mac only has one radio, so it can't be physically connected to more than one access point at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that Virtual Box can connect to a Wi-Fi network, because it installs a virtual device that simulates a cable connection. Its called "VirtualBox Host-Only Network" and is visible in the controll panel and the task manager.